Bulkification not working for Before Delete Record Triggered Flow
Issue:
The flow works for single record delete scenario, but not in the bulk record delete scenario.
It is written with assumption that Flows Bulkification is taken care by salesforce in these contexts.
Both single and bulk record creation scenarios are working properly.
Flow Description Below:
This is a Before Delete Bulk Trigger Flow written to update a field in Opportunity (Product List) when an Opportunity Line Item is created/Removed.
From the Delete Trigger Flow on Opportunity Line Item (can be called as OLI or Opportunity Product), I'm calling a subflow to perform these operations.
Parameters passed to the subflow - Record, RecordPrior, IsNew, IsDelete
For Delete operation in the subflow, first I'm using a Get Query to get all the OLI records of Parent Opportunity. Based on the context filtering it to remove the deleted record. Then looping the filtered list to prepare a comma separated Text variable which I'm updating in the Parent Opportunity.
Below are the screenshots:
(Comments are added to the picture for better understanding)
Subflow part 1:

Sublflow part 2:

Collection Filter:

Product list Assignment :

I'm not able to figure out the the problem. Kindly share your inputs and help me resolve this.
